# Kubeconfig for deploying to all namespaces in a k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking at instructions on how to go about generating a kubeconfig file that can deploy, delete my k8s deployment to all namespaces and also have have permissions to create, delete and view secrets in all namespaces.

The use case for this kubeconfig is to use it in Jenkins for performing deployments to a kube cluster.

I am aware of k8s service accounts with role and rolebindings, however it appears they can be used to only to specific namespace(s)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should create cluster role and cluster role bindings to grant access cluster level. Then using the service account that has cluster level access, you should be able to do the stuff across all namespaces.

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide an example?

Comment: https://medium.com/containerum/configuring-permissions-in-kubernetes-with-rbac-a456a9717d5d

Comment: Thanks. But again this article talks about namespace specific permissions. I am interested in a user that can perform operations against cluster wide namespaces.

Comment: You need to go through the post completely.